# Duplicate entries created on simple INSERT

Tags: php, sql, oop, pdo

OK after 40 years I am trying to move to OO PHP.

Everything going OK except when I do a very simple INSERT then two almost duplicate (id not duplicated) rows are created.

The table consists of a autoincrement INT id,  a VARCHAR msg field and an INT image field defaulted to NULL. With every insert I get a duplicate msg. id works fine.

I fear this may be something to do with the way I am using PDO.

Connection established as:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hjoyjoy;dbname=$dhaphap", $usadsad, $pborbor);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

Class Message gets sent a message which is stored by the setMessage method and then uploaded to the DB by the storeMessage method:

```
class Message 
{

    protected $_message='Message not set';
    public $id =10;

    public function setMessage($mess)
    {
        $this->_message = $mess;
    }

    public function displayMessage()
    {
        return $this->_message;
    }

//need try/catch safety sections
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@********************zxzxz

    public function storeMessage()
    { 
        global $pdo;
        $sql = "INSERT message (msg) VALUES ('$this->_message')";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute();
    }
}// end CLASS "Message".
?>

<?php
$test = new Message;
$test->setMessage("Dumbo!!!");
$test->storeMessage();
$info=$test->displayMessage();
echo "<h2> $info </h2>";
?>
```

I have been looking at this for hours but darned if I can see what I have done wrong.

Comment: i don't see here how the insertion is being duplicated, since you only call the `storeMessage()` once. these are the only codes?

Comment: In this case, how msg is inserted? `Dumbo!!!Dumbo!!!`?

Comment: Why aren't you using `bindParam()` to specify the value, instead of interpolating the variable?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Do you call setMessage method in second insert?

Comment: Either something in the script is calling `storeMessage` twice, or something is running the script twice. Check your webserver log to see if the script is being run twice.

Comment: what about the forgoten `INTO` in the sql query?

Comment: @Marcio... I shd have been clearer. I get:

    19   Dumbo!!   NULL
    20   Dumbo!!   NULL

Comment: @Barmar do I NEED a `bindparam()`. I am starting v simple and building up. I could try a bp but do not see how that changes anything,

@rogelio added the INTO (thanks) - no difference :-(

Comment: best to learn good habits from the beginning. Interpolating variables is error-prone. You'll get a syntax error if you try `$test->setMessage("That's dumb");` because of the quote character.

Comment: how to you access the script? Have you include the script in other file?

Comment: Talking about good habits, i discourage you to use `global` variables too, they can generate big headaches

Comment: @roelio I just run a page message_class_test.php with what you see (PDO instantiated via an include). (Left out the retrieveMessage method for clarity). But this really is all there is.

I have done a `FIND ALL` looking for "store" and it only occurs as the class name and the call. Off to try a bindparam!

Comment: @Barmar changed method to:
`    public function storeMessage()
    { 
        global $pdo;
        $temp=$this->_message;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO message (msg) VALUES (:val)";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':val',$temp);
        $s->execute();
    }
Still same problem.
`
I went to look at the Apache logs but only `error.log` is running. Sorry to be dense but where do I turn on the `access.log` (I presume that is where I should be looking?) PS Sorry cannot get the code to appear properly.

Comment: when you insert a new row, are you looking directly from the database?

Comment: @BeNice I never meant to suggest that using parameters would solve this problem. I don't know much about configuring apache, so I don't know how to enable the access.log.

Comment: @Marcio yes the `global` did not seem right. Just starting OO and saw this somewhere. I couldn't see how to access the `PDO` object inside the `class`. Before I have just had the include PDO as a bit of magic as an INCLUDE and then just used it as a connection.

I tried not using global but then I seemed to need to pass PDO as a variable into every method that I wanted to be able to have DB access in. What is the "right" way of doing this and should we be discussing this here or should we PM or start a new question or can you point me to an answer. Many thanks for you useful nudge tho.

Comment: OK I ported this up to a live server and the problem disappeared. Thanks for all your help. It appears to be an Apache setup problem or something like that. I think I should close this down and open up an Apache query. I am quite new here so not exactly sure how to proceed but suspect that is it. Once again thanks.

Comment: If you want i can post an answer refactoring your code to eliminate the use of `global`