# INSERT produces duplicate entries on local machine but not on live server

Tags: windows, apache, webserver, xampp, localhost

EDIT: I suspect this is a problem with my Windows setup for localhost or a problem with Apache settings or a hidden process which is causing a mySQL `INSERT` statements to be run from two different routes.

Running XAMPP on local machine. When using a very basic `INSERT` into mySQL it produces duplicate entries. On my shared hosted server it does NOT. IE the problem is not the code it is with Apache/conflicting with something else or something like that.

Here is what happens locally. If I `INSERT` foo bar into my message table from this:

```
public function storeMessage()
{ 
    global $pdo;
    $temp=$this->_message;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO message (msg) VALUES (:val)";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':val',$temp);
    $s->execute();
}
```

in the database I get

```
id=24 msg=foo bar
id=25 msg=foo bar
```

One maybe relevant point - I installed Laravel with Oracle VM VirtualBox and Homestead and so on. I cannot see anything starting on its own but I had to do a lot of tweaking to get it working ...

I have spent hours trying to sort this. Somewhere I saw changing port numbers on XAMPP would help. For a moment it seemed to but only in some transient way. I could not get my localhost alias directories to work properly and I am not sure exactly what I did that worked for a minute or two about two hours ago (sorry beyond exhausted).

1) Has anyone experienced anything similar (it is NOT a simple coding problem I 100% sure)?

2) can anyone suggest tools or processes to try and see what is going on (I have looked at all the error and access logs and nothing seemed relevant)?

Grateful for any thoughts.

PS Original post was here - but that was all about what I was doing wrong coding wise.

[Duplicate entries created on simple INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310437/duplicate-entries-created-on-simple-insert)

Comment: And how is that connected to Laravel? I don't see you use here Laravel DB class. Probably you make some redirection that runs function `storeMessage` twice. You can use debugger or simply add to the beginning of the function `echo "I'm running";` just to make sure this function is run only once

Comment: we can only see the function and there's nothing wrong with it. There might be some code that is invoking your function or your browser is sending twice request that might execute the function twice.

Comment: Append to _message some global counter which will be incremented inside storeMessage() before insertion. Then msg should look like "foo bar 0", "foo bar 1"... If you get 2 different messages, then your function is called twice, and the problem is out of this function scope

Comment: This is NOT a message of PHP/mySQL code - I am 99% certain of that. (Laravel is not used at all.) In total we are looking at a hundred line which work fine on a hosted server. A call to insert foo bar is sent from a very simple PHP program running just on a XAMPP stack. But somehow that `INSERT` operation gets performed twice. The only reason I mentioned Laravel is that I installed it a week or so ago and it is the only thing that I can think of that I have installed that might possibly be causing this weird situation. Probably in the editing of the local hosting settings. But I am flummoxed.

Comment: In Dreamweaver CS6 when I save a PHP file it is actually running it. I am so tired. This is not normal is it? This _may_ be what is happening - not 100% sure it is JUST what is happening now.Any thoughts pls